# How do I import 3rd party libraries in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I installed 3rd party libraries with npm. For example, I'd like to import the library on my page at "https://github.com/xkeshi/image-compressor". But the "import ImageCompressor from 'image-compressor.js" error that I wrote at the beginning of the page shows me the "window is not defined" error.

How to get a third-party library in NextJS?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do a dynamic import for the component that is using the 3rd party library.

```js
// components/my-awesome.component.js
// import the library that use `window` object
import grapesjs from 'grapesjs';

export default function MyAwesomeComponent() {
  // Initialize your component or do whatever you need to do
  ...
}
```

In the page definition, import your component by using `dynamic` and disable SSR

```js
// import dynamic method from next
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
// import your component with dynamic and disable SSR
const MyAwesomeComponent = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/my-awesome.component'),
  {ssr: false}
);

// use your component
export default function () {
  return <MyAwesomeComponent />;
}
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import